# Login in as a brand new admin user and sonar just refreshes the page and does not log me in

Tags: sonarqube

I have setup sonar source on a tomcat 6 server (ubuntu OS) and use mysql for a database. The application is taking traffic successfully i.e. I am able to see ///sonar

I have integrated this with Jenkins (Hudson) and the build is able to update the tables of sonar via the plugin and I can view the report from ///sonar.

The problem is in login, I click login (top right) and provide admin/admin credentials, but the page refreshes and keeps me logged out (still login link displayed). I tried a different data to verify if the authentication is correct and it throws out proper authentication errors.

I am not able to view the configuration setup page for the admin account to create account or import new profiles etc.

Any help is appreciated on this issue. Even pointers on debugging is much appreciated.

Thanks,
-- Dinesh D

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this using Sonar 2.8 with Atlassian Crowd. For some reason, Sonar and Chrome don't always get along. Try logging in with Firefox or IE and see if you get different results.

Comment: yah this worked for me... I'm wondering if it may be due to the fact that I was using a self-signed cert (https), and firefox was able to add the security exception. Thanks!

Comment: this didn't work for me I used 3 different browsers still refreshes on login

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the admin password, or removed and re-added the admin user?  That would explain it.

Have you tried [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Ilosttheadminpassword)?